# How to send HTML as a response in REST?

Tags: html, node.js, rest

I have created an API in `Nodejs`. I have tried creating a call which returns `HTML` to display a site in the browser.

My Call looks like this:

```
router.get('/displayHTML', checkAccessToken, (req, res, next) => {

if (req.query.data === undefined) {
    return res.status(900).json({
        message: 'Data does not exist'
    });
}

Data.find({ data: req.query.data}).exec()
    .then(data => {
        if (data.length < 1) {
            return res.status(400).json({
                message: "Nothing found"
            });
        }
        // I need to return HTML here so the user sees something in his browser
        return res.status(200).json({
            data: data

        });

    }).catch(error => {
        return res.status(500).json({
            message: error
        });
    });



});
```

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Headers/Content-Type

Answer (score 1):

Check the fs_library:  https://nodejs.org/docs/v0.3.1/api/fs.html

```
var http = require('http'),
lib = require('fs');
lib.readFile('./page.html', function (err, html) {
    if (err) {
        throw err; 
    }       
    http.createServer(function(request, response) {  
        response.writeHeader(200, {"Content-Type": "text/html"});  
        response.write(html);  
        response.end();  
    }).listen(8000);
});
```