# How can i add CSS in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, css, node.js, express

i want to add CSS in my res.send output how can i do it....
or is there any way to do so...

[Like when i run the code the output is this (images)][  [1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/GDhBX.png]

and i want to add css in "This item has been saved to the database"

```
app.post('/contact', (req, res) => {
    let myData = new moon(req.body)
    myData.save().then(() => {
            res.send("This item has been saved to the database")
        })
        .catch(() => {
            res.status(400).send("item was not saved to the databse")
        })
});
```

Comment: like what css info? Give a use case

Comment: You are only sending json from here. You can either send html file from server with styling applied or html string in json form with styling.

Comment: Maybe the better way will be redirect (with text 'This item has been saved to the database' or something else) to another subpage with defined styles?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

or you can build a HTML with a link to a css file and then sendFile("contact.html"); for the contact route

when receiving a post submission

```
 app.post('/contact', (req, res) => {
    let myData = new moon(req.body)
    myData.save().then(() => {
            res.send('<p class="success">This item has been saved to the database</p>")
        })
        .catch(() => {
            res.status(400).send('<p class="error">item was not saved to the databse</p>")
        })
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You could try sending it as HTML with a class. From there you can pre-code the CSS which should automatically apply to it. :\

[This](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59478371/how-to-send-html-as-a-response-in-rest) could be helpful for that.